# simplified/alternative version of std::bind()/ tr1::bind()

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I am using C++03.  Thus I don't have `std::bind()`.  My compiler is ported from g++, but `tr1::bind()` is not ported.

I want to bind a function having 3 arguments.  Thus `std::bind1st()` and `std::bind2nd()` won't work.  In addition, neither `std::bind1st()` or `std::bind2nd()` deal with reference type of argument.

Thus I am writing my own version of `bind1st()` as follows, including sample invocation of my `bind1st()`:

```
#include <iostream>

// c++03 does not define nullptr
#ifndef nullptr
#define nullptr ((void*)0)
#endif

namespace mybinder {

void *binder3ArgToBind;
void *binder3FunctorToCall;

template <int uniqueID, typename USER_FUNC_TYPE, typename BOUND_FUNC_TYPE,
          typename returnType, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class binder3  // 3 arguments binder
{
public:
    static void setParams(void **pArg1, void **pFunc) {
            *pArg1 = binder3ArgToBind;
            *pFunc = binder3FunctorToCall;
            binder3ArgToBind = nullptr;
    }

    static returnType f_bound1st_common(T2 &arg2, T3 &arg3) {
        static void *arg1;
        static void *func;
        returnType ignored;

        if (binder3ArgToBind != nullptr) {
            setParams(&arg1, &func);
            return ignored;
        }

        return ((USER_FUNC_TYPE)func)(*(T1*)arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }

    static returnType f_bound1st(T2 arg2, T3 arg3) {
        return f_bound1st_common(arg2, arg3);
    }
    static returnType f_bound1st(T2 &arg2, T3 arg3) {
        return f_bound1st_common(arg2, arg3);
    }
    static returnType f_bound1st(T2 arg2, T3 &arg3) {
        return f_bound1st_common(arg2, arg3);
    }
    static returnType f_bound1st(T2 &arg2, T3 &arg3) {
        return f_bound1st_common(arg2, arg3);
    }

    static BOUND_FUNC_TYPE bind1st(USER_FUNC_TYPE f, T1 &arg1) {
        binder3FunctorToCall = (void*)f;
        binder3ArgToBind = (void*) &arg1;

        (*(void (*)())f_bound1st_common)();
        return f_bound1st;
    }
};

}

using namespace std;
using namespace mybinder;

typedef short (*FUNC)(int const, int&);

// test function
short f(int &a, int const b, int &c)
{
    int val = 100 * a + 10 * b + c;
    a+=100;
    c+=10;
    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[2] = {2, 5};

    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
        // bind function f with a[i] as its 1st argument.
        FUNC ff = binder3<__COUNTER__, short(*)(int&, int const, int&), short(*)(int const,int&), short, int, int const, int>::bind1st(f, a[i]);

        int k;
        int m;
        for (m=0; m<2; ++m) {
            k = 1-m;
            cout << "before: a[i]=" << a[i] << endl;
            cout << "before: m=" << m << endl;
            cout << "before: k=" << k << endl;
            cout << ff(m, k) << endl;
            cout << "after: a[i]=" << a[i] << endl;
            cout << "after: m=" << m << endl;
            cout << "after: k=" << k << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And the execution results:

```
before: a[i]=2
before: m=0
before: k=1
201
after: a[i]=102
after: m=0
after: k=11

before: a[i]=102
before: m=1
before: k=0
10210
after: a[i]=202
after: m=1
after: k=10

before: a[i]=5
before: m=0
before: k=1
501
after: a[i]=105
after: m=0
after: k=11

before: a[i]=105
before: m=1
before: k=0
10510
after: a[i]=205
after: m=1
after: k=10
```

It works fine on my PC, as an emulation.  However, it raises several problems in my embedded compiler:

(1) The embedded compiler does not support `__COUNTER__`

(2) The invoke of `bind1st()` is tedious, and those redundant types in the template may get problem, if they are not synchronized.

Thus my question:

(1) How do I implement `__COUNTER__` as in regular g++/gcc? Or, In fact, I only need a unique number/identifier than a counter.

(2) Is there anyway I can derive argument types and return types from the function pointer type?

(3) Even if Question (2) can be done, can I derive bare types from a reference type? For example, can I derive `int` from `int &`?  Please note that the source type can be `int` or `int &`, and I need to derive the resulting type `int` in both cases.  Please note that it's C++03, not C++11 or higher.

(4) Any other suggestions? Perhaps someone can provide a simpler or better implementation?

The goal of Q.2 and Q.3 is to make template call shorter, like `FUNC ff = binder3<__COUNTER__, short(*)(int&, int const, int&)>::bind1st(f, a[i]);`.  All other types can be derived from the first function pointer type.  In addition, I don't have to write 4 overloads.

---UPDATE---

Since the implementation uses pointers to get the binding argument and the function, it may have a potential bug/design flaw:

If the caller changes the value of the binding variable after it calls `binder3<...>::bind1st()`, but before the use(call) of the bound function, the effective value is the value AFTER change, not BEFORE change!
Currently I can live with it, by careful coding.  And normally I use(call) the bound function right after the bind1st() (without any command in-between).

Ideas to improve this problem are welcome.

--UPDATE--

Currently, use of `__COUNT__` contains a bug: Since `__COUNT__` is not globally unique (restart count from zero for each compilation of .cpp file), the bounding variable may be overwritten, if they are not used promptly.  If I can get a program-wide global unique number to replace `__COUNT__`, the above implementation should be good enough (except for those tedious stuff).